# How to use web3.filter to check if the transaction is processed

Tags: solidity, web3js, ether

i am trying to send ether to an account and then deploying a contract with that account. So i need to setup a watcher which triggers when the transaction is completed or mined, so that i can deploy the contract.
watcher using 'pending' and 'latest' does not trigger on the transaction getting mined. So i tried for putting a watcher for the address, but it does not trigger.

Code:
"Setting up watcher for that account"

```
web3.eth.filter({address: "0x7480e208a68aae46d96cad5341ae111a2a86dcf6"}, function(error, result){
  if (error){
    return console.log(error)
    }
    console.log("----filter-----")
    console.log(JSON.stringify(web3.eth.getBalance("0x7480e208a68bae46d06cad5341ae111a2a86dcf6")))
    console.log(result);
    console.log("----filter-----")
});
```

Now doing the transaction.

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({ from: web3.eth.coinbase, to: "0x7480e208a68bae46d06cad5341ae111a2a86dcf6", value: 10000000000*4 })
```

Very new to this, please let me know what would be the correct way to do this.

Comment: You shouldn't need to specify an address with filter for block notifications. Try without.

Comment: Yup i was wrong. Need to provide "latest" or "pending". In my case "latest".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The web3.eth.filter method only listens for logs (i.e. Events that are fired by a contract) but not for normal transactions to/from a particular account (source: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethfilter)

You could setup a filter with the "latest" argument to get new blocks and query the transactions of that block. Here's a snippet that I've used to do the same:

```
var filter = web3.eth.filter("latest",function(error, blockHash) {
    if (!error) {
        var block = web3.eth.getBlock(blockHash, true);        
        if (block.transactions.length > 0) {
            console.log("found " + block.transactions.length + " transactions in block " + blockHash);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(block.transactions));
        } else {
            console.log("no transaction in block: " + blockHash);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Done Master!!!!!